# Cairo blur surface

Tags: c, gtk3, cairo, gaussianblur, pangocairo

I can't figure this out , can you guys help a bit

I have am original cairo surface `srf` and its context `c`

now I am creating another surface `shadow` and superimposing it on previous one by

```
cairo_t *cr = c;
cairo_surface_t *shadow = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height);
c=cairo_create(shadow);
draw_rounded_rect(c, x_o+offset, y_o+offset, width, height, radius_int, 1, 1);
cairo_set_source_rgba(c, 0, 0, 0, 1);
cairo_fill(c);

blur_image_surface(shadow,10);
cairo_set_source_surface(cr,shadow,x,y);
cairo_paint(cr);
cairo_surface_destroy(shadow);
c=cr;
```

The blur algo I'm using is from official cairo doc [here](https://cairographics.org/cookbook/blur.c/), which works separately

superimposition also works perfectly, but surface is not blurred at all